# spell:suggest with wrong order?

Tags: marklogic

I am using [`spell:suggest`](https://docs.marklogic.com/spell:suggest) to query a dictionary.
I would assume that the result is ordered by distance. But this is not the case, as [`spell:suggest-detailed`](https://docs.marklogic.com/spell:suggest-detailed) shows in the following example.

Example:

```
spell:suggest-detailed("/my-dictionary.xml", "cohn", 
  <options xmlns="http://marklogic.com/xdmp/spell">
    <distance-threshold>10</distance-threshold>
    <maximum>3</maximum>
  </options>
)
```

Result:

```
<spell:suggestion original="cohn" dictionary="/my-dictionary.xml" xmlns:spell="http://marklogic.com/xdmp/spell">
  <spell:word distance="10" key-distance="0" word-distance="50" levenshtein-distance="1">coin</spell:word>
</spell:suggestion>
<spell:suggestion original="cohn" dictionary="/my-dictionary.xml" xmlns:spell="http://marklogic.com/xdmp/spell">
  <spell:word distance="10" key-distance="0" word-distance="50" levenshtein-distance="1">conn</spell:word>
</spell:suggestion>
<spell:suggestion original="cohn" dictionary="/my-dictionary.xml" xmlns:spell="http://marklogic.com/xdmp/spell">
  <spell:word distance="9" key-distance="1" word-distance="45" levenshtein-distance="1">crohn</spell:word>
</spell:suggestion>
```

The distance of the third result is 9, which is less than the distance of the first two results which have a distance of 10.
Is there an error in the ordering?

Answer (score 5):

The primary sort key is Levenshtein distance, then key distance, then word distance.

Here the Levenshtein distance is 1 for all of them, the key distance is 0 for the first two, so that is why they are ahead of the last one.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation.